# Cumulative sum with array in C++

Tags: c++, cumulative-sum, montecarlo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
  
int iData, tData;

void randgen(int max, int min){
  srand((unsigned) time(0));
}

int main()
{
  cout << "Masukkan jumlah data: ";
  cin >> iData;
  int jData[iData], randNum[iData], fProb[iData];
  double probkei[iData], tKumul[iData],tepiA[iData], tepiB[iData];
  int tData;


  for(int i=1; i<=iData; i++){
    cout << "Masukkan data ke-" << i << ": ";
    cin >> jData[i];
    tData += jData[i];            //jumlahkan seluruh data untuk mencari probabilitas tiap variabel
  }system("cls");

  probkei[0]=0;

  cout << setw(10) << "Data ke" << setw(10) << "Frekuensi" << setw(15) << "Probabilitas" << setw(20) << "Kumulatif" << setw(10) << "Interval" << endl;
  for(int i=0; i<iData; i++){
    probkei[i] = (double) jData[i]/tData;         //typecast integer to double for the probability
    if(jData[i]==jData[1]){
      tKumul[i] = probkei[i];
    }else if(i<i+i){
      tKumul[i] = probkei[i] + probkei[i+1];       //for cumulative sum 1 way
    }
    probkei[i] = round(probkei[i] * 1000.0) / 1000.0; //rounding the probability
    tKumul[i] = round(tKumul[i] * 1000.0) / 1000.0;
    cout << setw(10) << i+1 << setw(10) << jData[i] << setw(15) << probkei[i] << setw(20);
    int temp;
    cout<<"data "<<probkei[i]+probkei[i+1];        //for cumulative sum 2 way
    
    
    cout << setw(10) << tKumul[i] << endl;
    /*if (i == iData || jData[i] != jData[i - 1])
        {
            temp += count;
            cout << "Cumulative frequency of " << jData[i - 1] << " in the array is: " << temp << endl;
            count = 1;

        }else{
          count++;
        }*/
  }
  cout << setw(20) << "Total data: " << tData << endl;
 return 0;    
}
```

I want to count cumulative frequency from my array data.
First is entering the value/total of the number of data in the array. Next is entering the value for each data one by one and then counting all probabilities of each data(the possibilities are declared in double). And then counting the cumulative which is sum the n data with the n+1 data. And the last is making the top and bottom edges for each data to be used as a random number interval.
I've done my best and finding the solution but I still confused why it's doesn't work.
I was trying to count it in 2 ways but all of them do nothing.
This is a Monte Carlo Simulation.

example [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSwv8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```cpp
int iData;
cin >> iData;
int jData[iData];
```

is using variable-length arrays, which are not standard C++. Rather use `std::vector` instead:

```cpp
int iData;
cin >> iData;
std::vector<int> jData(iData);
```

---

The `tData` local variable is uninitialized:

```cpp
int tData;
...
tData += jData[i];
```

It should be initialized to 0.

---

The condition `i<i+i` doesn't make sense.

There is something weird going on with the indexes. The input is loaded from index 1 but the second loop starts from 0. This loading from 1 is also not accounted in size of the arrays, so the last element will overflow the array.

There is something wrong with this too:

```cpp
tKumul[i] = probkei[i] + probkei[i+1];
```

If this is supposed to be cumulative sum then `tKumul` should appear on the right side too.

---

If we load data from 0, then the second loop should look like this:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < iData; i++) {
    probkei[i] = (double) jData[i] / tData;
    if (i == 0) {
        tKumul[i] = probkei[i];
    } else {
        tKumul[i] = probkei[i] + tKumul[i-1];
    }
```

With this code ([see godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmZqQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTFxtpj2eQxCBEzEBBk%2BflzllWk1dQQFYZHRsfEKtfWNWS2Dnd1FJf0AlLaoXsTI7BzmAMzByN5YANQma25Og8SYrPvYJhoAguub25h7B8gsTAQI55c3ZhsMW167%2B0OqBeDDwCQ%2B11uv3ujzcADdMA4SBCrl4UkYdsw2AoEkxljtBuh9lZIddggQdi9ghAZnsAOwkq47Zk7NBeCmAwF7OIAWSYCi8AGtBYYdtofAYEDt0K8mCBuWZiZ8WTtyaqACKypXXFXIYKPC5rbAarVrRkqwkgEAIpHEQHk85izW1CB4Z1MGbapksy3WxFEO0HdALCL0R0JYioCKCzB4V3uuY7AgAaR8Xlo8dlnrNn2VLLVBHd%2B3VGi9eeZ/GIO1dglVj3VO1LZrrXLdposqus1lpJgZ5ZVrIWHIOXPMZj5AuFopltR2MYAtGPYa3lwcFfKx16Byy9QwDY7tEWAKwWPAmI/qrfbpPu7lWNYNw9ak9ni9X5m9y86ndD1duHauLQZbfsybLDm4XJKAQADuEBcBoPYjmuY63jGS6cmuUGwfBiEQchcQAGInIKXiMCk6FIf%2BWFwUeuGjnEyiRhETARHQhD8hReFUZgMEQGYCF/gqqYsOmrx4FQnFcoB747JW1Zqng9aNsSLZrm2tQqWeljdvS5rXhGUYxq%2Bp7ng2xbVsGXihpgtJPhpL6mTsAD0N7tv2KrifJ9bmQJvZ6deLIpmmQEOReSkGdGsbniZb45iBA6fgBtBKLp7nXkFIkhTFZkPjsEVGdFr5mZYSbCemhXzlwpkySqn5pcy%2BVRaFOUNpGXgMOgECNcZRU7AAVDs8EaBoAB0AkuUNo1Nv5A4ZeVzVKW1HUQHNWW9QNk1jbSE3DVNNU/uygnUThglaRYXBHTx2G%2BZRTrPtll28VwtGCd1hWORh3G8fxdFrqt71hZ9AEdUBcXeh%2BdJfuDg6HUD1E/YJY4ACqoLUtDSrKG5xIJhayoJ0lgyqJwEIse7TbmkOfBwcy0JwR68H4HBaKQqCcBB2klQoCxLA86w8KQBCaNTcwIKcWAxDSpCCiAR4aPonCSAzQss5wvAKCAcuC0z1OkHAsBIJgqiIuyJDkJQdTAAoyiGBUQgIKg0GM/zaAsAkdBiQI1shLQdsO4zzMu279AxJbzAJAo9sEKQgd0NEADy7K%2B47yuG4iVzEJbqukKnyA1PgjNHp8hfXPBnzPZ8/EV/TMiCCIYjsFINfyEoajK7o8QGEYKBdpY%2Bh4BE6uQHMqAJFU6scPOADqYjo1PhsEMQTA7POCSYDKgh4Mgavc8seiEsEXu2/byfawLJwrPz0GLwknA8DTdNK6frMcNgRvICbVaqAAHAAbPOP%2BSB2MAZAyBqwL3aoKWkEB2ZWF7jsXAhASDcjWFwGYvAtZaBmHMaWst5YcEVqQFgEhhqkH9rwZ%2BasNYCyFlgvBZhH7MwodQ7WtCETEBSM4SQQA)) the output is:

```
   Data ke Frekuensi   Probabilitas           Kumulatif
         1         5          0.067               0.067
         2        10          0.133                 0.2
         3        15            0.2                 0.4
         4        20          0.267               0.667
         5        25          0.333                   1
        Total data: 75
```

---

In addition I would suggest using `fixed` and `setprecision(3)` instead of manual rounding:

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(3);
```

and using algorithms instead of loops. Calculating probabilities can be replaced by `std::transform` and calculating cumulative sum can be replaced by `std::partial_sum`:

```cpp
std::transform(
        jData.begin(), jData.end(),
        probkei.begin(),
        [tData](auto elem) { return (double) elem / tData; }
);
std::partial_sum(probkei.begin(), probkei.end(), tKumul.begin());
```

With this code ([see godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxHoADqgKhE4MHt6%2BcQlJAkEh4SxRMVy2mPaOAkIETMQEqT5%2BRXaYDskVVQQ5YZHRegqV1bXpDX3twZ353VwAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMzByN5YANQmy25OvcSYrDvYJhoAgitrG5jbu04shnixJ2eXZqsM615bO24Abk0iMRXhcrl8bnc3GJgCRCAgWKD3p9vr9dgwfNE8KZlqcLl5EkZNsw2ApYkwFpteugdlYwRdggRNo9ghBJtsAOx086bXmbNBeJl/P7bMxmACyTAUXgA1jLDJttD4DAhNugmJUQKKzLS3nzNoyDQARDVMXUXfXIYJ3U6442m808vnUkAgQEOEh/RknRUmyoQPB%2BpiTR36l1uoGe3boWYReg%2B2LEVARGWYPABoPTTYEADSPi8tAzppDy25er5hoIQbuRs2GlDfP4xE2AcEBprddp7ZFgYdpYN1ms7JMXPL%2Bt5AqFuxF5glUtl8oYatNm1TAFpZ1Ce1vdtqtbOG%2BP%2BdbXnbtEGTABWCx4K9Gw/jqsrwfLWvnh3X2%2BX%2B%2Blsec%2B8Wnyk47m4myuLQjp/uGBDEIYChNiwEB/kevLvpUAB0UTAKyWZoUw6GuGypDIShibJqmeCYZg2EMERJFHleFhPpUd4QEwgqoGB9AsMOXKbIcBBzEuEAxl4caYOyJSYCwmwAPTZhe/YjgBTq8iW3JhgQ6CuuS1R4GIAD60qIWRKZplRNFEZspkUQRDDoFZub5rQFk4epbx/sBwq7koBAAO4QFwGjDtOu6ztWqabt5oG%2BQFQUhW4M5igAYocMpeIwiRRaFMWYP5gWXglSVmMoSYREwER0IQUrZYlPl5QFZjBSB2p5iwBYangVC1SK4EPl5OWbDQqiYOgLW%2BYmTR4IkAgQMs7mAbyTYtoaeAdvW/ZrT2ikWAOlhDpyGkoQNdW5fl8UtbelhcONDWBc10W%2Bh%2BN53rd52FS1NlpoxX61o9sUQE1RW7k57UQZ%2Br2PX1v6Lf%2BnmzFOp1UndQMtbOAAqqCVLQy6atqLXMUwLXQ0dvICUJnYw5cHIqRw0y0Jwl68H4HBaKQqCcIl%2B2WFSszzLcKw8KQBCaHT0wIEcWAxERMogJeGj6JwkjM6L7OcLwCggArIus3TpBwLASCYCNyAcWQFBscQwAKMohglEICCoH5LNC2gLCxHQnUCLbIS0A7Tss2zbse/QMTW8wsQKI7BCkMHdDRAA8oK/vO6rxtNOcVuaxwvDp8gFT4Czl5vMXFxBW8XCl%2BcTVvGYTMyIIIhiOwUgN/IShqKruhmPohjGIOlj6HgESa5A0yoLEZQMNna4AOpiDjc/GzBRNrrEo2GI4yAa3zCw9FpwQ%2B/bjup7rwuHIsQt%2BbBsScDw9OMyrZ8cxw2Am2bmyqAAHAAbGuP%2BSE2MAZAyAWwwS8AwGU7IIBcysIPTYuBCAkFFMsKYvAdZaEmNMWW8tFYcGVqQFgEgNAK0DrwF%2BGstbC1FlgvBZgn5swodQ3WtDATEBmn4SQQA)) the output is:

```
   Data ke Frekuensi   Probabilitas           Kumulatif
         1         5          0.067               0.067
         2        10          0.133               0.200
         3        15          0.200               0.400
         4        20          0.267               0.667
         5        25          0.333               1.000
        Total data: 75
```

Comment: Thanks, dude. Honestly, I'm still new about this and I just know a really basic of c++ programming. I don't even know about your recommendation in using fixed and setprecision(3). Can you tell me how can I get deeper into all of these things?

Comment: But, why did you recommend me to use fixed and setprecision() instead of the manual way? what is the difference?

Comment: It may be just my opinion but I think it conveys the intent better. It also leaves the values of the variables intact.